# Navigation Controller Embedded in Tab Controller - Tab Bar not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a `Tab Bar Controller` with 3 views embedded in it : 2 are normal `ViewControllers` and one is a `Navigation Controller` which has a `ViewController` with a `CollectionView` as in the picture below. Now when I first enter the `Tab Bar Controller` and navigate between the tabs, everything is fine.

If I press any object in my `collectionView`, a new view gets pushed onto the `navigationController`. The problem occurs if I then press the `back` button and pop that view in order to return to the view containing the collectionView. In this situation,  the tab bar on the bottom of the screen becomes invisible.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? 
`segue.destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

If that doesn't fix then use `unwind segue`

Comment: In which controller should I put this line?

Comment: in your `tabBarController`s `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: I didn't assign any swift file to my TabBarController. I just have a segue which loads it from my loading screen, its the arrow which comes from the bottom of the screen into the tab bar controller